# Ordering posts by an array

Tags: wp-query, order

I have a query that returns a number of different custom post types. I want to order the array of posts by the content of an array of post types; e.g. `array('post', 'video', 'testimonial'..... );`

The array , the order, is fixed.

How can I manage this without making a different query for each post type?

Comment: what is the content of the other array ? custom-fields?

Comment: Post types, i.e. I want a list of related posts but I always want the posts at the top, followed by the videos etc (I have 7 custom post types)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with native API and you will probably have a rather bad time hacking up SQL for it.

This would be *quite* trivial to re–sort posts like this *after* they are retrieved with PHP code. if you use `get_posts()` you get array you manipulate already and for a `WP_Query` object array of results is available in public `$posts` property.

Note this assumes you don’t need to *paginate* this query. In which case things get very messy very fast and back to the mountain of custom SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `foreach` loop to display your content in this order.  loop through the values in your array, in each loop have a `foreach` statement that loops through your posts and checks if the post type equals the value in your array that it is currently on.

```
$query = //whatever your query is;
$array = //your array

foreach ($array as $value) {
    foreach ($query as $post) {
        if ($post->post_type == $value) {
            //code to show that thing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would have less overhead that repeating the query?

Comment: Yeah repeating queries is almost always going to take more time than looping through results.  think of it this way.  using multiple queries you're just sending the parameters of the foreach loop to your SQL database and that search is being performed and the results sent back to your web server.  using PHP you're just getting all the results from your database and then doing the search on your web server.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to mrben522 for pointing the way;

```
<?
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID),
    'posts_per_page' => 7,
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) ,
  );

  $related = new WP_Query($args);
  if( $related->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <ul class="related-posts">

        <?
        $array = array ('article', 'post', 'video', 'webinar', 'factsheet','whitepaper', 'casestudy');

        foreach ($array as $value) {
            while( $related->have_posts() ) : $related->the_post() ;
                if ($post->post_type == $value) {
                    get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'related');
                }
            endwhile;
            rewind_posts();
        } 
        ?>

    </ul>

<? endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```